# Brownian motion random walk with decaying steps

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems

Is there any work on Brownian motion with decaying steps?

For example variations such as:

(1) a random walk in which nth step is $+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ or $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ length of equal probability.

(2) a random walk where nth step has possibilities of $+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, 0, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ each of 1/3 probability.

I am interested in finding the effect - if any - such variations have on the growth rate, which for +/-1 is given by:

$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log n}} = 1 $$

Intutively I feel, the first modification should result in:
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2\log\log n}} = 1 $$
and second may result in:
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{2S_n}{3\sqrt{2\log\log n}} = 1 $$
but I would like to look at some proofs in this area.

Comment: what if the steps were $+/- \frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$ or $+/- \frac{1}{n^{0.4}}$ Does the same theorem apply? In other words is there some step where they don't converge, and in such case what is the asymptotic behavior

Comment: @SangchulLee Doesn't the 3-series theorem require $\sum_{n=1}^\infty var(X_n 1_{|X_n| < K}) < \infty$ for some $K > 0$?  That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Your increments are uniformly bounded by $1$, so any number $K$ larger than $1$ will work. Also, for your edited question, I believe that we can consider the Skorokhod embedding and then what will replace the role of $n$ in the asymptotic envelope $\sqrt{2n\log\log n}$ for the SRW in LIL should follow from the embedding.

Comment: Thanks. I will look it up.

Comment: @SangchulLee If $K > 1$, $1_{|X_n| < K} = 1$ so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty var(X_n 1_{|X_n| < K}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty var(X_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n = \infty$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user6247850, That comment is pertaining to OP's original question, where the increments are $\pm\frac{1}{n}$ with equal probabilities.

Comment: A quick googling reveals that, not so surprisingly, we have an extension of the law of iterated logarithms to a more general independent sum, namely the [Kolmogorov's law of iterated logarithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266226480_A_note_on_Kolmogorov's_law_of_iterated_logarithm).

Comment: @SangchulLee if the random walk with steps were to be $\pm \frac{1}{n^a}$ with equal probability of sign, and for any $a > \frac{1}{2}$, am I correct in thinking the two series theorem may suffice to prove that $\sum_n X_n$ will converge almost surely?